# Why is search form input data not being passed to its child component in React?

Tags: reactjs, components

In this weather app, I want the user to type a city into the "Body" component and have the weather results for the city display by updating the "Results" component.

I'm struggling to get the search query stored as `{this.state.city}` into the API call when exporting it from "Body" as prop `cityProp={this.state.city}`.

I'm able to access and log the inputted city name to the console. However, submitting it appears to have no effect on the location being displayed.

The goal is to display the temperature for the inputted city.

App:

```
import "./App.css";
import Header from "./Header";
import Body from "./Body";

function App() {
  return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <Body />
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Body:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import Results from "./Results";
import { useState } from "react";

class Body extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { city: "London" };
  }
  handleCityChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ city: e.target.value });
  };

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // this.setState({ city: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <form className="SearchForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            <input
              value={this.state.city}
              onChange={this.handleCityChange}
            ></input>
            <button>Go</button>
          </label>
        </form>
        <Results cityProp={this.state.city} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Body;
```

Results:

```
import "./App.css";
import React from "react";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Results = (props) => {
  const [forecast, setForecast] = useState([]);
  const [location, setLocation] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getWeather = async () => {
      try {
        fetch(
          `http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=47b6acea5d204134b4661938220707&q="${props.cityProp}"&days=3&aqi=no`
        ).then((response) => {
          response.json().then((data) => {
            setForecast(data.forecast);
            setLocation(data.location);
          });
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error");
      }
    };
    getWeather();
  }, []);

  const renderedContent = forecast.forecastday
    ? forecast.forecastday.map((item) => {
        return (
          <div key={item.date_epoch}>
            <div>{item.day.maxtemp_c}</div>
          </div>
        );
      })
    : null;

  return (

      <div>{renderedContent}</div>

  );
};

export default Results;
```

Comment: Why is `this.setState()` commented out in the submit handler function?

Comment: When it's active, it fails to pass any data into cityProp during export. I commented it out because it's not doing the intended job.

Comment: I understand about half of that solution and will search for the rest. I gather that useEffect needs to be told what to monitor. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect in your `Result` component will not run when `cityProp` updates unless the prop is in the effect's dependency array:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const getWeather = async () => {
      try {
        fetch(
          `http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/forecast.json?key=47b6acea5d204134b4661938220707&q="${props.cityProp}"&days=3&aqi=no`
        ).then((response) => {
          response.json().then((data) => {
            setForecast(data.forecast);
            setLocation(data.location);
          });
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error");
      }
    };
    getWeather();
  }, [props.cityProp]);
```

Comment: Ah, damn it's working even better than expected now. Realtime letter-by-letter searching means that user doesn't even have to complete the name of the city. Many thanks, I understand what I was doing wrong. useEffect's dependency array is the (usually empty) array which you can populate with the incoming data you want it to monitor. Many thanks, big breakthrough.

Comment: Ah, right, since you are updating the state/prop in the change handler, you don’t need the submit handler to update the state, so you don’t need to uncomment that line.

Comment: It was a duplicate while I was experimenting. I'll take the credit haha. But seriously thanks, this all just clicked. 3 days I've been stuck on this! Most probs just come from lacking the vocabulary to phrase the question. If someone had just whispered "dependency array" to me 3 days ago...